# Поворот черепашки на точку (x, y)

Tags: python, graphics

Какой метод в библиотеке turtle (python) устанавливает поворот черепахи на конкретную точку (х, у) если не известен угол поворота?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для вычисления градуса поворота по координатам можно воспользоваться математической функцией atan2.

```
angle = math.atan2(y,x) * 180 / math.pi
```

Comment: лучше наверное будет воспользоваться `math.degrees(...)` - `math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))`

Comment: Ребят, спасибо вам обоим большое! Ваши способы почти рабочие (там только один нюанс есть), но я все-таки нашел "черепаший" метод, который как раз возвращает угол к произвольной точке (х, у) от положения черепашки: turtle.towards(x, y)

Comment: @Panteliymas прошу прощения, я почему-то подумал что вы просмотрели [документацию по turtle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) и не нашли там этого метода :-/. С другой стороны вы теперь знаете как поворачивать предметы без специального метода. Нюанс я так понял заключается в вычитании координат, чтобы черепашка была в точке 0,0: `angle = math.atan2(y - y0, x - x0) * 180 / math.pi` и учесть текущий угол

Comment: @AlexKrass я посмотрел документацию, но либо старой версии, либо просто проглядел (что скорее всего) данный метод. Нюанс вы поняли правильно. И верно подметили, с другой стороны я теперь больше знаю :)